# Display all details of particular user only when click on his name

Tags: php, html

I have a page which show the details of all the user.When I click on a particular user it should display all the info of the user.

Here is my first page code.

```
echo '<td><a href=\'merchant_action.php?merchantdetials='.$row['Establish_name'].'\'>'.$row['Establish_name']. '</td>';
```

I have used this code for linking to the other page.

`if(isset($_GET['Establish_name']))
{                                                                 $email=$_GET['Establish_name'];                                                          $sqls =("select * from merchant_details where Establish_name='$email'");              $results = mysqli_query($db,$sqls);                                                      $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results,MYSQLI_ASSOC) ;               $Cname=$rows['Establish_name'];                                                           echo $Cname;`

The Problem is that no data is been displayed.
please hep me out.

Comment: there is no Establish_name parameter in your GET request

Comment: Replace `$_GET['Establish_name'])` with `$_GET['merchantdetials'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (isset($_GET['merchantdetials'])) {
    $email   = $_GET['merchantdetials'];
    $sqls    = ("select * from merchant_details where Establish_name='$email'");
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $sqls);
    $rows    = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $Cname   = $rows['merchantdetials'];
    echo $Cname;
}
```

Your query string param's name is **merchantdetials**.

Give it a try, it should work.